# error by vs error of vs apostrophe

Tags: prepositions, phrases, conjunctions

In Hindi there's a word that tells 'relation' between subject and the noun/action. To represent the same in English, we use *by / of / apostrophe* in English.

Some examples in English are:

1. *Tom's* car
2. Car *of* Tom
3. Painting *by* Tom

In these example, I quite understand each of them. Now I have the sentence which I have problem with. I can't decide which one to use to show this 'relation'.

Suppose someone (Tom) made a speech error (e.g. incorrect pronunciation) and people who were listening to him started laughing.

Now I can't decide which of 3 'methods' to use to show this relation between him and the action (speech error).

Three possibilities I can think of are:

1. People are laughing at speech error *by* Tom
2. People are laughing at speech error *of* Tom
3. People are laughing at *Tom's* speech error

In my opinion, all 3 are kind of telling same relation. And all 3 are correct.

I guess this thing is called preposition. I'm not fully sure though. When I looked definitions of *of* and *by* in dictionary, they mentioned it as *preposition*.

I maybe wrong that's why I asked this question so I know the correct phrase/word/method to describe this kind of 'relation'.

Comment: Tbh this wasn't proofreading

Comment: "Which is correct?" looks like proofreading to me. An on-topic question here is clearly about a specific English language topic, but this question doesn't mention one. Maybe your topic is how to describe someone's speaking mistake, or how to make a noun phrase from something someone has done? I'm just guessing because it's unclear what English topic you're having trouble with. On-topic questions also show what work you've done already to answer the question yourself, including what you found, and what aspect you still need help with. Fix those things, and I'll happily reopen :)

Comment: @gotube I have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that 3 is the best, 1 is almost correct but not as common. It should be *People are laughing at **a** speech error **made** by him*. Option 2 is just wrong.